# Adding to PATH system variable using a bat file

Tags: command-line, path

I want to run a .bat file once and add multiple values to my path environment variable. I'm having all sorts of problems with it.
Well, first, I want this file to check if any entries are already on the path, and add only if it's not there. Second, some paths have spaces on them, and I can't make it work, this is my current file:

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set list= "d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\php\\"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\php\ext"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\php\imagick"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\node.js"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\PortableGit\cmd"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\Web\python"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\\[ Tools \]\7zip"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\\[ Tools \]\youtube-dl"
set list=%list%;"d:\Dropbox\Apps\\[ Tools \]\y33be-dl"

:: iterate over the paths list
for %%a in (%list%) do (

    echo %%a

    Echo.!PATH! | findstr /c:%%a>nul && (
        Echo.TRUE
    ) || (
        Echo.FALSE
        setx PATH /m "%PATH%;%%a"
    )

)



@echo on
```

Any ideas about how to make this work?

Comment: set does not have anything for spaces. It takes everything after the =, including spaces, so just use normal spaces, don't escape them at the set level. You have to escape them at other places though.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)